# How do I proceed from here for factorization of likelihood / joint normal density for finding sufficient statistics?

Tags: sufficient-statistics, factorisation-theorem

I'm trying to show that the statistic $\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i, \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i^2 \right)$ is sufficient for $\mu$ where $(Y_1, \dots, Y_n)$ is a random sample from $N(\mu, \mu)$ for $\mu > 0$. I want to use the [Fisher–Neyman factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Fisher%E2%80%93Neyman_factorization_theorem), of the form $L(\mu; \mathbf{y}) = g(T(\mathbf{y}), \mu) \times h(\mathbf{y})$. I proceed with the likelihood / joint density as follows:

$$\begin{align}L(\mu; \mathbf{y}) &= \prod_{i = 1}^n L(\mu; y_i) \\ &= \prod_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \mu}} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu}(y_i - \mu)^2 \right\}} \\ &= \dfrac{1}{(2 \pi \mu)^{n/2}} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - \mu)^2 \right\}} \\ &= (2\pi \mu)^{-n/2} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - \mu)^2 \right\}} \\ &= (2\pi \mu)^{-n/2} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2 - 2\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i \mu + \sum_{i = 1}^n \mu^2 \right) \right\}} \\ &= (2\pi \mu)^{-n/2} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2 - 2\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i \mu + n\mu^2 \right) \right\}}\end{align}$$

How do I proceed from here?

---

### EDIT

Problem 9.59 from [here](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/%7Egrw/Classes/2016-2017/2017Spring/Math472_1/Assignment09.nb.html) seems to agree with my work.

Comment: You're done, because your final expression is manifestly a function only of the sum of squares of the data and the sum of the data.

Comment: @whuber So we have $T(\mathbf{y}) = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i, \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i^2 \right)$, $g(T(\mathbf{y}), \mu) = (2\pi \mu)^{-n/2} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2 - 2\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i \mu + n\mu^2 \right) \right\}}$, $h(\mathbf{y}) = 1$?

Comment: Your notation seems to obscure what's going on.  If we write $T(y)=(t,s),$ it would read $$g((t,s),\mu) = (2\pi\mu)^{-n/2}\exp(-s/(2\mu) + t - n\mu/2).$$

Comment: @whuber What is $t$ and $s$? I don't see anything similar here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Fisher–Neyman_factorization_theorem

Comment: *Compare the expressions.*  It should be obvious that $t=\sum y_i$ and $s=\sum y_i^2.$

Comment: @whuber Ahh, ok, I see.